# Iterate over table filling 2 HasSets in a functional way in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I'm writing a Scala app and trying to iterate over a table (in form of a 2-dimensional Array) in a functional way. For every line in the table I want to fill a Set with all distinct values from the first column and a second Set with all distinct values from the second column.

I tried many approaches but could not find any solution how to do it in a functional style. Because I get 2 new variables from the iteration, it seems impossible without non-functional help.

Here is a non-functional example with mutable HashSets for a table with products and customers:

```
val myInputTable =
  Array(Array("Product A","Customer 1"), Array("Product B","Customer 1"),
    Array("Product C","Customer 2"), Array("Product A","Customer 2"))

val productSet = new collection.mutable.HashSet[String]
val customerSet = new collection.mutable.HashSet[String]

for(
  inputLine <- myInputTable;
  inputElement <- inputLine
) {
  if (inputLine.indexOf(inputElement) == 0) {
    productSet.add(inputElement)
  } else {
    customerSet.add(inputElement)
  }
}

println("Product Set:")
productSet.foreach(println)
println("\nCustomer Set:")
customerSet.foreach(println)
```

Is there a way how I could do this with immutable Sets, other objects or maybe the for-yield syntax?

Thanks for any answers or hints,

Felix

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any time you find yourself trying to FP-ify some code that iterates over a sequence while updating some mutable state, a good first approach is to use `foldLeft`:

```
val myInputTable =
  Array(Array("Product A","Customer 1"), Array("Product B","Customer 1"),
    Array("Product C","Customer 2"), Array("Product A","Customer 2"))

val (products, customers) =
  myInputTable.foldLeft((Set.empty[String], Set.empty[String])) {
    case ((ps, cs), Array(p, c)) => (ps + p, cs + c)
    case ((ps, cs), _) => (ps, cs) // Alternatively fail here.
  }
```

The first argument to `foldLeft` is the initial state. We want to work with two immutable sets, so we use a tuple of `Set.empty[String]`. The next argument to `foldLeft` here is a function:

```
  {
    case ((ps, cs), Array(p, c)) => (ps + p, cs + c)
    case ((ps, cs), _) => (ps, cs) // Alternatively fail here.
  }
```

This should be a function from the currently accumulated state `(ps, cs)` and each element `Array(p, c)` to the next state. It will be applied to every function in the collection from left to right (hence `foldLeft`), accumulating the state changes, and it will return the final value of the state. It works like this:

```
scala> val (products, customers) =
     |   myInputTable.foldLeft((Set.empty[String], Set.empty[String])) {
     |     case ((ps, cs), Array(p, c)) => (ps + p, cs + c)
     |     case ((ps, cs), _) => (ps, cs) // Alternatively fail here.
     |   }
products: scala.collection.immutable.Set[String] = Set(Product A, Product B, Product C)
customers: scala.collection.immutable.Set[String] = Set(Customer 1, Customer 2)
```

In some cases there may be more specific combinators that allow you to express your operation more concisely, but `foldLeft` is a good general starting place that allows fairly straightforward translations from mutable to purely functional code.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe just [transpose](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Array.html#transpose[U](implicitasArray:T=%3EArray[U]):Array[Array[U]]) would do a job for you?

```
val table = Array(
      Array("Product A","Customer 1"),
      Array("Product B","Customer 1"), 
      Array("Product C","Customer 2"),
      Array("Product A","Customer 2")
)

val Array(productSet, customerSet) = table.transpose.map(_.toSet)

productSet //Set(Product A, Product B, Product C)
customerSet //Set(Customer 1, Customer 2)
```

Comment: Thanks Krzystof, this is right and does solve exactly the problem I described, and is also very concise as well. I intentionally kept my example super simple, to not add unnecessary complexity. I my real case I have some more columns and do combine also more columns into sub lists, what a transpose can probably no longer solve. But thanks a lot, your answer is correct as well, so you get a +1 ;)